# $A'B=I \rightarrow B'B \geq (A'A)^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, inequality

Could anyone please help me show that for general matrices it holds that $$A'B=I \rightarrow B'B \geq (A'A)^{-1}$$

Thanks.

Comment: use $B=(A^\prime)^{-1}$

Comment: @Thomas Then you're assuming that $A$ is invertible. That is not given.

Comment: Perhaps this is a stupid question but what does the inequality mean in the matrix context and what does the prime denote?

Comment: @Dreamer: Not at all. Thomas uses the *fact* that $A^{\prime}$ is invertible (note that $A^{\prime} B = I$.)

Comment: @GrahamHesketh The prime is a way of denoting a transpose. The inequality means that each element of $B'B \geq$ each element of $(A'A)^{-1}$

Comment: @Dreamer: Do you mean that they are not square matrices? Then vous avez raison. Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: @eltonjohn Exactly. Not *necessarily* at least. $A$ and $B$ should both be general matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$\left[\array{A'\\B'}\right]\left[\array{A &B}\right]=\left[\array{A'A & I\\I &B'B}\right]\succeq 0.$$ Thus for all $u,v$ 
$$u'A'Au+v'B'Bv+2u'v\geq 0.$$

With $u=-\left(A'A\right)^{-1}v$  we get

$$v'\left(A'A\right)^{-1}v+v'B'Bv-2v'\left(A'A\right)^{-1}v\geq 0\\
\iff v'\left(B'B-\left(A'A\right)^{-1}\right)v\geq 0\iff B'B\succeq\left(A'A\right)^{-1}.$$

Comment: For any matrix $Q$, $Q′Q$ is positive semi-definite. You see it immediately when you write down the definition.